# Delphi iOS uisupportedinterfaceorientations faill to transport

Tags: ios, delphi, mobile, firemonkey, portrait

When transporting the .ipa file generated by Delphi 11.3 to macos ventura 13.5.1, and defining "orientation" > "enable custom orientation" > "portrait" in the project settings, so that the user cannot change the direction of the application, I I get the error

```
Asset validation failed (90474) Invalid bundle. The “UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait” orientations were provided for the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations Info.plist key in the xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx bundle, but you need to include all of the “UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight” orientations to support iPad multitasking. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uisupportedinterfaceorientations. (ID: aacf3264-9e0f-4ffd-875d-8b87f2480082)
```

I tried to transport the file, I found an error

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, follow the steps ->

Open delphi > project > options > Application > version info >

Select target ios realise > scroll bar to bottom > right click and select "Add Key"

Include UIRequiresFullScreen in key, and YES in Value.

Save and rebuild the .ipa file

Transport the new file.